# My user ID and password is correct: can not log in to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: log

I have a dual boot in machine with windows7 and Ubuntu.

While I was installing Ubuntu, it prompted me for a name and a password 2 times. I gave a user name and put my password 2 times and wrote it down in a place so that I do not forget. When I reboot my system it shows 2 operating systems. When I go to windows 7 it works  perfectly. When I go to Ubuntu it shows login and guest login. When I go to login, enter my user name and the password that I have written while installing, it shows invalid username or password.

**I have uninstalled and reinstalled 3 times and each time same thing happens.**

I am new to Ubuntu. Please let me know if anyone can help.

Comment: I am pretty sure that my login and password are correct

Comment: Two things I can think of, both silly. First is it could be capslock. The other is for some reason you're using the wrong keyboard layout

Comment: I slightly changed you post. Please look at it. If you disagree with the changes then you can revert them.

Comment: As mentioned by Journeyman, it is probably an issue with the keyboard layout. Check out your usual keyboard layout and compare it with the american one: http://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/topics/keyboards/registry_index.html

Answer (score 0):

I would try booting into the recovery system and resetting your user account password to something simple like 'password'. Here are the instructions to resetting a lost password: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword

Once you have done that reboot and log in with the simple password. If you can get in then there shouldn't be anything wrong with the authentication. You can then reset it back to something else.