# Cannot change my password for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login, suspend, password

I have followed this question [To change password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319697/unable-to-log-in-and-unable-to-reset-the-password). But now I have issues when I open my Chrome browser and when I try to change password from 'Sysmtem Settings'.

[image]

As you can see the 'change' button is still disabled. When I open my Chrome browser it asks for a [pasword fo keyring](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31786/chrome-asks-for-password-to-unlock-keyring-on-startup) but when I enter my 'new password' I had set in previous step it doesn't work. When I suspend or logout, my 'new password' works. What could be the problem, are there two passwords and I have just changed one of them in step 1.

Comment: Try launching "Seahorse" (also known as "Passwords & Keys") and select the "Passwords > Login" keyring in the left side bar. You can right-click on it and change the password there. That should be the keyring which is used by Chrome (but also for some other OS passwords like wifi etc.). You should probably set that to the same password you use for login. Does that help? (Note that I'm mainly guessing here, not exactly sure whether my advice will be useful or bad)

Comment: No it did not work, it asks for the old password which I don't have anymore. Should I delete it, there is an option to delete it.

Comment: Deleting that keyring will make you at least lose all the credentials stored inside it. Please don't, I have no idea how much of an impact this will have. As I said, my knowledge in this special area is limited, I'm mostly guessing here.

Comment: I am open to taking the risk of deleting the keyring, but If I delete that how will I get the option to make a new one.

Comment: There should be a button/menu entry in Seahorse, but I can just again say I don't know whether this will do good. Proceed at your own risk. I'm out.